# Verificar si un dato ya existe en una tabla y dar una condicion

Tags: php, mysql, crud

tengo una pagina llamada categories, en donde hay una lista de categorías que el usuario va creando, y estas se van agregando a una tabla llamada categories que se compone únicamente de dos columnas (id y name)..ahora bien , el usuario también tiene la opción de crear y actualizar categorías, lo que yo quisiera y la verdad no se como hacerlo es que si por ejemplo el usuario ingresa en el campo crear o actualizar categoría una que ya existe, lance un mensaje y no pueda ejecutarla, por ejemplo supongamos que ya existe la categoría **Hamburguesas** y el usuario intenta actualizar o crear una categoría llamada **Hamburguesas** o bien **hamburguesas** no se ejecute y lance el mensaje.
Aca dejo el código de la pagina actualizar categoria.

````
    require 'database.php';

    if(!empty($_GET['id'])) 
    {
        $id = checkInput($_GET['id']);
    }

    $name = "";

    if(!empty($_POST)) 
    {
        $name   = checkInput($_POST['name']);
        $isSuccess  = true;
       
        if(empty($name)) 
        {
            $nameError = 'Este campo no puede estar vacío';
            $isSuccess = false;
        }
        

        else
        {
            $isSuccess = true;

        }
         
        if ($isSuccess ) 
        {
        $db = Database::connect();
        $statement = $db->prepare("UPDATE categories  set name = ? WHERE id = ?");
         $statement->execute(array($name,$id));
        }

            Database::disconnect();
            header("Location: categorias.php");
        }

    else 
    {
        $db = Database::connect();
        $statement = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM categories WHERE id = ?");
        $statement->execute(array($id));
        $category = $statement->fetch();
        $name  = $category['name'];
        Database::disconnect();
    }

    function namelExists($pdo, $name) {
        $stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT 1 FROM categories WHERE name=?");
        $stmt->execute([$email]); 
        return $stmt->fetchColumn();
        // found
    }
 

?> ```
````

Answer (score 0):

Debes tener en cuenta la acción que se va a realizar, por que si solo verificas que el nombre no exista previamente, funcionará bien cuando se trate de agregar una nueva categoría, pero sí hubo algún error y deseas modificar 'hamburguesas' para poner mayúscula inicial, y el juego de caracteres de la base de datos es insensible a mayúsculas y minúsculas, no te va a permitir el cambio.

Envía a la función ID como tercer parámetro y puedes asignar un valor por defecto (si lo deseas). Además, asegúrate de devolver falso o verdadero, que se puede hacer fácilmente [contando el número de filas obtenidas](https://www.php.net/manual/es/pdostatement.rowcount.php):

```
function namelExists($pdo, $name, $id = 0) {
    // Se va a buscar si el nombre ya existe y no es igual a ID
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT 1 FROM categories WHERE name = ? AND id != ?");
    $stmt->execute([$name, $id]);
    // Mayor que cero devuelve true, igual que cero devuelve false 
    return ($stmt->rowCount() > 0);
}
```

Facilita el proceso, identificando qué es lo que se va a hacer:

```
require 'database.php';

// Siempre define la variable $id, la vas a necesitar
// Se puede hacer con asignación ternaria
$id = (isset($_GET['id'])) ? checkInput($_GET['id']) : 0;
$name = "";

if(!empty($_POST)) {
    $name = checkInput($_POST['name']);
    $isSuccess  = true;
   
    if(empty($name)) {
        $nameError = 'Este campo no puede estar vacío';
        $isSuccess = false;
    } else {
        $isSuccess = true;
    }
     
    if ($isSuccess ) {
        $db = Database::connect();
        // Verificar si la categoría existe
        if(namelExists($pdo, $name, $id)) {
            // Marcar error para evitar duplicados
            $nameError = 'Ya existe la categoría';
            $isSuccess = false;
        } else {
            // Si $id es cero, se va a insertar, de lo contrario, actualizar
            if($id == 0) {
                // Insertar
                $statement = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO categories SET name = ?");
                $statement->execute([$name]);
            } else {
                // Actualizar
                $statement = $db->prepare("UPDATE categories  set name = ? WHERE id = ?");
                $statement->execute([$name, $id]);
            }
            // Desconectar y redirigir
            Database::disconnect();
            header("Location: categorias.php");
        }
    }
} else {
    $db = Database::connect();
    $statement = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM categories WHERE id = ?");
    $statement->execute(array($id));
    $category = $statement->fetch();
    $name  = $category['name'];
    Database::disconnect();
}
```